# mediaelement.js not play youtube video

Tags: wordpress, video, mediaelement

I have Download files form http://mediaelementjs.com/ and include all file which was needed. 
After to add that i try this code.

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
<source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" />
</video>
```

But its not Show Video Player , But if i call m94 videos then its working .
Can You Please help. 
I am using in WordPress